# How to stop screen from changing how emacs handles colors

Tags: font-lock, colors, bash

In .screenrc, I have this line: `term xterm-256color` If I do not use that, or if I try something different (like `xterm-color` or `screen-256color`), then emacs has absolutely no color.

Here is a font-lock setting in emacs outside screen, displaying everything correctly.

[image]

And here are those same settings while inside screen.

[image]

The settings for the comment, doc, and preprocessor faces are forced to be inverted background/foreground despite what the settings state.

Here is an example of the atrocious highlighting in action:

[image]

How do I fix the colors? Should I cross-post to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) or [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) instead?

Comment: What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable? It should be something like `xterm-256color`.

Comment: @Lindydancer The value of `TERM` both outside and inside screen is set to xterm-256color. I confirmed both by using `echo $TERM`.

Comment: Things to try: force screen to use your chosen screenrc with `screen -c myscreenrc`. force screen to use your chosen term with `screen -T xterm-256color`. This is really an issue w/ screen's handling of termcap/terminfo. You _could_ work around it by redefining all your colors in emacs, or learning termcap/terminfo and customizing your term setting in your screenrc (man screen, search for "termcapinfo"). I recommend neither. give `byobu` or `tmux` a try. this mess is exactally why i personally switched to `tmux`